# Why cant List<decimal> be casted to List<int>?

Tags: c#, generics

The following code gives an `InvalidCast` Exception

```
int newValue = new List<decimal>() { 6m }.Cast<int>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Even though `decimal` can be casted `int`, why can it not be done in a list?

Edit:
To clear up the question, I want to know why the cast part of the equation throws an exception. Just running `new List<decimal>() { 6m }.Cast<int>().ToList()` Would also give an `InvalidCast` Exception

Comment: Int can be casted as decimal but no the inverse. you are looking for `int newValue = new List<decimal>() { 6m }.Select(v=>Convert.toDecimal(v)).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Covariance and Contravariance in Generics https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Franck That should be posted as an answer, not as a comment. It may not even be what the OP is looking for, though, and even if it is, it's a poor method of doing so.

Comment: @Franck also, you can actually cast both ways. Difference is, from Int to Decimal is implicit, whereas from Decimal to Int has to be hard-casted. Aka. (int)decimalVariable

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard i should have specified it couldn't be cast implicitly. anyhow that's a wierd piece of code he should use `int value = 6;` and it should even be a constant :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

```
new List<decimal>() { 6m}.Select(d => (int)d).ToList<int>();
```

or

```
new List<decimal>() { 6m}.ConvertAll(d => (int)d);
```

use `Select` with any `IEnumerable`, `ConvertAll` will only work with `List`

`.Cast` should be used when you need to process members of (for example) an array list as if they were strongly typed.

thanks to @hvd for correcting me

Comment: No, the OP definitely isn't trying to cast `List<decimal>` to `int`. And if all of the elements in the list should be converted (it's not clear to me whether that's what the OP wants), `.ConvertAll(...)` is often a better option than `.Select(...).ToList()`, and probably is here.